# Laravel response transformations not working

Tags: php, json, rest, laravel

I have the following

### controller function

```
 public function show()
    {
        $users_id = Request::segment(4);
//        $this->user_bank_details_repository->setPresenter(new UserBankAccountPresenter);
        $account = $this->user_bank_details_repository->findByField('users_id', $users_id, $columns = ['user_bank_details_id','bank_name','bank_account_number','bank_ifsc_code','beneficiary_name','bank_account_type','bank_branch','created_at']);
        if(!$account)
        {
           return $this->response->noContent();
        }
        return $this->response->item($account, new UserBankAccountTransformer);
    }
```

### Transformer

```
   <?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
namespace App\Api\V1\Transformers;

use App\Entities\UserBankDetails;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class UserBankAccountTransformer extends TransformerAbstract {

    public function transform(UserBankDetails $bank_details)
    {
            return [
                'id'=> (int) $bank_details->user_bank_details_id,
                'bank_name'     => $bank_details->bank_name,
                'bank_account_number' => (int) $bank_details->bank_account_number,
                'bank_account_type' => $bank_details->bank_account_type,
                'bank_beneficiary_name' => $bank_details->beneficiary_name,
                'bank_branch'=> $bank_details->bank_branch
            ];
    }
}
```

I am using repository pattern design and using dingo for my REST framework.

I always get the response as

```
{
  "user_bank_details": [
    {
      "user_bank_details_id": 1,
      "bank_name": "jbjb",
      "bank_account_number": "939393933939",
      "bank_ifsc_code": "ABCD0000047",
      "beneficiary_name": "Gaf",
      "bank_account_type": "savings",
      "bank_branch": "Mad(E)",
      "created_at": "2015-12-23 17:05:39"
    }
  ]
}
```

instead of the transformed json. I dont get any errors as well. Tried using

```
 return $this->response->item($account, new UserBankAccountTransformer::class);
```

But still the response is not getting transformed. I tried whatever I could but I dont get it worked :(

Comment: And what exactly method `item` for response does? It's not default Laravel response, isn't it ?

Comment: @MarcinNabiałek  Right.its not laravels. I am using Dingo framework. https://github.com/dingo  . In their documetation its mentioned to use it for responding with a response.

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is over a year ago, however for the sake of anyone who would have similar issue, the suspect here is the fact that you used: `item` instead of `collection`.

If the `$account` contains a collection, then it means this answer is correct: that is, this:

```
return $this->response->item($account, new UserBankAccountTransformer::class);
```

Should be:

```
return $this->response->collection($account, new UserBankAccountTransformer::class);
```

> PS: I also Encountered this on Laravel 5.2.* thats why I feel this might help.